# how do i get 4 dropdown list values from different rows in a loop in PHP?

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, foreach

i have to get values of different dropdown list from different rows in a loop. And looping is always not same e.g one time loop runs 5 times , and next time may be 50 times. Please help me how i can get values. Thanks
Here is code:

```
'<th>
   <select name= "$allocation[]" class="form-control ">
       <option>Select Faculty</option>
   <?php
   foreach ($faculty_selected_course as $faculty) { ?>
       <option><?php echo $faculty;  ?></option>
   <?php
   }
   ?>
   </select> 
   </th>

   <th>
      <select name= "$allocation[]" class="form-control ">
            <option>Select Other Faculty</option>
      <?php
      foreach ($other_faculty as $otherfaculty) { ?>
            <option><?php echo $otherfaculty;  ?></option>
      <?php
      }
      ?>
      </select>
      </th>

      </tr>
      <?php goto again;
      }
      ?>
      </th>

      <th>
          <select name= "$allocation[]" class="form-control ">
              <option>Select Faculty</option>
          <?php
          foreach ($faculty_selected_course as $faculty) { ?>
              <option><?php echo $faculty;  ?></option>
          <?php
          }
          ?>
          </select>
          </th>

          <th>
              <select name= "$allocation[]" class="form-control ">
                  <option>Select Other Faculty</option>
          <?php
              foreach ($other_faculty as $otherfaculty) { ?>
              <option><?php echo $otherfaculty;  ?></option>
              <?php
              }
              ?>
         </select>
         </th>'
```

Comment: For what reason are you using `goto again;`?

Comment: I am using if else statement in row.

Comment: again:
                        ?>
                        <tr class="odd gradeX">
                        <th><?php echo $course_loop++; ?></th>
                        <th><?php echo $course; ?></th>
                        <th><?php echo $course_title; ?></th>
                        <th><?php 
                        if($course_credit_hour==3){
                            echo "Class";
                        }
                        elseif($course_credit_hour==4){
                            echo "Lab";
                            $course_credit_hour--; ?>
                        </th>

Comment: Are you sure that you do not always call `goto again;`?

Comment: Yes i don't call goto each time.

Comment: Well then i don't understand your question

Comment: Please just tell me how i can get dropdown list values that are taken in a loop. And each row has 2 dropdown list. And number of rows change each time. Thanks

Comment: @Shakeeb how about accepting answers to your previous questions before asking new ones? This is not how SO works.

Answer (score 0):

If you would have an array like this:

```
$dropdown = array(
    'Faculty 1' => array(
        0 => 'f1 course zero',
        1 => 'f1 course one',
        2 => 'f1 course two'
    ),
    'Faculty 2' => array(
        4 => 'f2 course four',
        5 => 'f2 course five',
        6 => 'f2 course six'
    ),
    'Faculty 3' => array(
        0 => 'f3 course zero',
        1 => 'f3 course one',
        2 => 'f3 course two',
        4 => 'f3 course four'
    )
);
```

Then you could generate drop-down list's like this:

```
$htmlstr = '';
foreach($dropdown as $faculty => $list){
    $htmlstr .= "<select name=\"".$faculty."\">\r\n";
    foreach($list as $key => $name){
        $htmlstr .= "<option value\"".$key."\">".$name."</option>\r\n";
    }
    $htmlstr .= "</select>\r\n";
}
var_dump($htmlstr);
//echo $htmlstr;
```